# When export/import a site in sharepoint 2010 (WSS), error occur "A Web Part with this ID has already been added to this page"

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a webpart, and I insert that webpart into a site of Sharepoint 2010 (WSS).

I save a site as template by that site. After, I create a new site with that site template. I export this site, and after I import it.  I see a error in import site:

> "A Web Part with this ID has already been added to this page".

Please help me to fix it.

(It work well on MOSS 2010)

Answer (score 1):

Is new site is on the same farm as the originating site?, I would also asume that this is a Team site with Publishing features or a publishing site al togethere right?, if so, basically is having a conflict of GUIDS for a particular web part within a page or layout. If you see most of the site comming up, then is easier, because you could open the page or layout using SPDesigner and change the guids of the added webparts on the page; if not, you might need to crack open the template file and do it there.

Changing the GUIDS might help you to bring the page up, however any change done of the front-end could reverse the changes, so the best option is to edit the page and re-add the web parts, so it takes a new GUID for good.